# How can I Organize Games?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, menu

I am running 12.04 and am wondering if there is a way to organize games so that when I click on my "games" folder in the menu bar, all of my games will be in there.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the Dash

You can use the "DASH" (assuming unity is your interface).  Select the "**Application Lens "** and filter for **Games**

Answer (score 0):

## [Alacarte](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/)

Alacarte allows you to edit the menu system in Ubuntu. You should be able to organize your games folder with it easily.

Answer (score 0):

### **Install the Classic Menu Indicator on your Panel**

This gives you another option when you need to quickly browse and find your favorite applications such as Games, if the Dash is not your thing.

Press Ctrl – Alt – T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below to add its PPA.

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:diesch/testing

Next, run the commands below to install the package.

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator

Restart your computer and you will see the indicator menu on the top panel